# Split string and give in aggregation filter

Tags: java, string, mongodb, split, aggregation-framework

I have a String productname[abc,def].
I need to split this as below to give in aggregation filter like this.

```
Aggregates.match(Filters.in("productname", "abc","def"));
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Try `str.split("\\[|\\]|,");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from Eritrean is good, here's a complete solution using that regex:

```
String str = "productname[abc,def]";
String[] splitString = str.split("\\[|\\]|,");
List<String> result = Collections.singletonList(String.join(",", splitString));
```

The output of that will be: `[productname,abc,def]`